# Windows Form Application, need assistance

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I know I'm a bit underqualified to be on here, but seeing as my teacher is no good, was wondering if you could help with this extremely obscure problem that i have.

In this task, we have been asked to create a quiz through windows form application on c#. To be honest, I actually have no idea what I'm doing and am just trying to follow a booklet my teacher has given me. However, it appears this booklet isn't working, and the problem to obscure to be answered with a youtube video.

The problem I have is that I am running the form, and recieving problems when I click a button to access a different form within the program, and instead of just opening the linked windows form, it appears both forms remain open, regardless of the this.Close(); that I have coded. When both forms are open, I am unable to access the sought after form, as when i attempt to click on it it cuts back to the form where I initially clicked the link label. I realise this is very badly written, and I have no idea what I'm doing compared to you guys, but any input whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.

I have linked screenshots below. Ideally I'd like for the Program to run frmSplashScreen, the timer running out, then frmPlayerLogin, where I would click the link label to access frmPlayerSelectionNew.

Screenshot link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUJbR.jpg

Edit

I've been asked for the key code to be written here

The code on the frmPlayerLogin Screen relating to the link label is this.

```
private void lblClickToRegister_LinkClicked(object sender,        LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            Form myNextScreen = new frmPlayerSelectionNew();
            myNextScreen.Show();
            this.Close();
        }`
```

The code on Program.cs is as follows

```
`static void Main()
        {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new frmSplashScreen());
        Form myNextScreen = new frmSplashScreen();


        myNextScreen.Show();
```

Application.Run(new frmPlayerLogin());`

Comment: Please post your code (the relevant parts) as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: I would generally advise you to put your problem in your title.

Comment: I'd love to help but reading 8 screenshots worth of code to try and debug the issue is no good. I advise that you figure out how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and in doing so you'll likely resolve the problem.

Comment: Need assistance asking good question.  Read [Ask] and also take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

1. `ShowDialog()` is *modal*.  That means when you use it, instead of `Show()`, you are halting further execution until you enter a response and return a `DialogResult`

`myNextScreen.Show();`

2. We can't see the rest of your code from that image, and there's a way to post code on here.  If it's more than what I just pointed out, we'll need that to help.